# How to attract real-world radio telescopists to radio astronomy observational techniques questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-promotion

Here are ten questions about observational radio astronomy that are either unanswered (eight) or have no accepted answer (two). These are selected from my own questions only so far, there may be others as well. *Please feel free* to add other examples!

**Question:** How can we can bring questions about radio astronomy observational techniques to the eyes of radio telescopists? I'm thinking a note in a radio astronomy newsletter, or tweet with this list or link to this meta question by some radio astronomer or group, or similar?

We get great support for optics questions for optical telescopy, but not so much at the longer wavelengths.

Bounties I've added and automatic tweeeting indicated

currently no answers:

- [Did Arecibo's secondary optics compensate aberrations when viewing farther away from vertical?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28508/7982) +3/-0 `+100` **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1070649166509019141)**
- [How do radio astronomers avoid having their receivers burned out by ground-imaging radar from satellites?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34872/7982) +6/-0 **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1222897416686338048)**
  (https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1164190572900470784)**
- [How does Canada's radiotelescope CHIME manage polarization-dependent apodization of the fast f/0.25 optics?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28615/7982) +1/-0 `+100`
- [Is there work underway to push the long baseline capabilities of the Event Horizon Telescope to sub-millimeter wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35757/7982) +6/-0 `+100` **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1248037990561177601)**
- [How did Arecibo make radar images of ice on Mercury's poles?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31981/7982) +3/-0 **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1136558520365649920)**

answers but none accepted:

- [Why are the ALMA receivers' ADCs only 3-bits?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18052/7982) +8/-0 `+100` **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1136558520365649920)**

---

Answered and accepted since this was originally posted:

- [What is a radio "homology telescope" and is the 500m dish in China one?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16240/7982) +8/-0 **[tweeted]
- [Do ASKAP and ALMA have "fast dump" interferometric modes? Can they see and perhaps report Fast Radio Bursts in real time?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40664/7982) +4/-0 `+100` **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy/status/1356437196862062602)**
- [Hypothetical CMB space telescope design problem, received power from extended thermal source versus receiver front end NEP?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40125/7982) +0/-0
- [What telescope might this be a model of, with Sir Fred Hoyle?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28612/7982) +1/-0

Comment: The `community-ads` tag says "Indicates a post used for submitting and voting on Community Promotion Ads. For discussion on these ads, please use the [advertising] tag." Since we didn't have one of those, I've created it, though I'm not sure that description is a perfect fit here. Is there a better tag for this?

Comment: I removed the advertising tag. The Community Promotion Ads are a specific thing that graduated sites host on their own site. It is not for advertising our community elsewhere. That said we have put up ads for our site in the Community Promotion Ads of other sites (like Physics and Skeptics) before. We stopped doing it when no one volunteered to do the graphic design for the ad.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks for the assistance! I wonder if there is an alternate existing tag for general site promotion activities? If not, do you think one should be created? Without an applicable general site promotion tag I fear that the idea that a site can promote itself outside of SE will seem in appropriate. If it is inappropriate for some reason then my question is as well. But if we can talk about it, then perhaps there should be a tag for such a discussion?

Comment: I don't think it's inappropriate. We (the mods) have discussed some general site promotion ideas in the past. The tag for it is [tag:site-promotion]

Comment: @called2voyage I have no idea how I missed that, thanks!

Comment: @called2voyage May you elaborate on your comment about missing volunteers for a graphic design? I am willing to help, but rather new to the community.

Comment: @B--rian You can see our past efforts here: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/off-site-astronomy-community-promotion-ads

Comment: @B--rian For the current design limitations, just go to the meta of a graduated site we have been hosted at before (like Physics or Chemistry) and search for "Community Promotion Ads".

Comment: @B--rian If you decide to make one, just drop a new answer at the  Astronomy Meta post I linked, and if it gets upvotes, you can go ahead and submit it to the Community Promotion Ad posts on the other sites.