# How old is our Astronomy SE?

Tags: discussion

How old is our Astronomy SE ?. Unlike other sites, why there is poor patronage despite having great reception in Astronomy ? And what is the qualification to "graduate" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How old is our Astronomy SE ?

From the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest):

[image: Astronomy entry on the SE site list, indicating site age of 7y11m]

At the end of the entry it indicates that the site is seven years and eleven months old.

> Unlike other sites, why there is poor patronage despite having great reception in Astronomy ?

There are lots of ways to measure patronage. Astronomy actually has similar viewership to SE sites of comparable age. We also have similar post per day stats to sites of comparable age, though our trend line is a little more volatile. We also have a similar number of users to sites of comparable age.

Where Astronomy has struggled historically is building a sense of community and effective use of meta. Meta use has been up recently, which is also promising in terms of a community forming. Our chat room is still fairly unused. A thriving chat room is not necessary for a healthy site, however.

> And what is the qualification to "graduate" ?

We've gone over this recently. In a nutshell, the whole concept of graduation is more or less obsolete. If you want to know when we'll lose the "beta" label or get our own unique site design, the answer is we don't and can't know--possibly never! But that is not a bad thing, SE has said that established sites like Astronomy will stick around even if they remain in beta. We don't have to worry about getting axed.

For more info, see the [latest discussion on graduation](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753/6).